# Api to get list of products against product/brand name from Google or any other

Tags: google-api, e-commerce, product, google-shopping-api

I have a client who wants to have a feature in the app, where a user will enter the name of a brand or product and the relevant products will appear on the Table/List.
For this he doesn't want to make a commerce solution or product management solution of his own but to use any solution that is publicly available.
Now I need to know is there any platform that can serve the purpose ?
Does google have such public e-commerce solution ?
I have seen an app on Appstore called ProjectSeptember by ProjectSeptemberInc. They are using google search but I am not sure if they have made a solution of their own at Google commerce being merchant or are they using the one that I couldn't find out ?

Comment: this question is similar and has no answers yet :/  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29908712/product-database-or-api-to-get-product-info

Comment: hey! did you find any API source like this, Please update I have a similar requirement